# How do I match information in different sheets and copy/paste if there's a match?

Tags: excel, search

I have an Excel document with 5 sheets.

`Sheet1` is my **main sheet** with **3 columns** `A | B | C`. In the other sheets I have some text in `column A`.

Now I would like to match the text in `column A`, for all the other sheets, to `column B` in `Sheet1`. If it's a match I need to copy the information from `column B and C` in `Sheet1` to the corresponding sheet I used.

Comment: So you want to lookup the first column from `Sheet2-5`, see if you can find it in `Sheet1` and if you find something, copy the row to corresponding sheet?

Comment: @CustomX yes ^^ Thats it.

You explained better than me in one row ^^ sorry.

Just add, that I need to find all the column of Sheet2-5. (every sheet has +- 100 rows) and Sheet 1 has 3206

Comment: I would suggest using the `VLOOKUP() function`. I can add an example as answer, but I need to know one thing, do you need to check all 3 columns for the text or only the first and copy the other 2 columns? [info here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13780/using-vlookup-in-excel)

Comment: I need to search 1rst(column A) column from Sheet2-5, in the column 2 (column B) of Sheet1, and get if is it possible the column B and C, from Sheet 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy peasy lemon squeezy using the `=VLOOKUP()` function! ;)

Enter this in a cell in Sheet2 (e.g. B1): `=VLOOKUP(A1;'Sheet1'!B:C;1;0)` and in the cell behind this you copy this formula: `=VLOOKUP(A1;'Sheet1'!B:C;2;0)`

Now select both cells and pull the formula down. Repeat for the other Sheets! :)

Comment: Perfect!
But I have a little more question: 
I have donde what you said:
=VLOOKUP(A1;PORTALES!A:A;1;0)
And I get result the name searched. but I'm interested in get the next column of the Sheet1, so I changed a bit --> =VLOOKUP(A1;PORTALES!A:A;2;0) and I get #¡REF! but I dont understand why

Comment: You probably needed to change `;` by `,`?

Comment: @CusomX no no.. I found the problenm. I had to put in the range of all the table, something like : =VLOOKUP(A1;PORTALES!A1:C500;2;0) (for example)